# No resource identifier found for attribute 'contentDescription' in package 'android

Tags: android, xml

I had this warning before ""`[Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image`" on `ImageView` and then I added this code to it:

```
android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
```

and now I'm facing with an error

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'contentDescription' in package 'android
```

This is my code:

```
<ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="48dip"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
           />
```

Comment: Not an answer to the error, but you can savely ignore the warning. While it might be good practice to heed them, and also to add descriptions, it will work fine without them :)

Comment: I was so confused because at the first place I just had a couple of warning and no errors but I couldn't run the application, I don't know why!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a string resource named `desc` to your project (e.g., `res/values/strings.xml`) to use the `android:contentDescription` attribute as you have it.

Comment: I already have the desc string resource. But still doesn't work.

Comment: @user1143529: `android:contentDescription` was added in API Level 4. Set your build target to API Level 4 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you are sure there's no need in contentDescription for your element, you can make lint ignore it:

1. Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` namespace
2. Add `tools:ignore="contentDescription"` attribute to your element.